# Free .net library to convert Word to PDF

Tags: gratis, library, pdf, c#, asp.net

Is there any free .net library to convert word to pdf in asp.net for a C# application?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question I think you can use Free.NET Word Library. It designed for developers to create, read, write, convert and print Word document files from any .NET platform. You can download it by using [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=E-iceblueCoLtd.FreeNETWordLibrary).